# Linked list segmentation fault 11

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm having a problem with one of my homeworks. I need to do a linked list concat, but after redefining the operator+, I have segmentation fault. 
Here is the code:

In main.cpp:

```
case CONCAT:
        do
    {
      std::cout << "Which two list do you want to concat?(1-3) ";
      std::cin >> s;
            std::cin >> g;
            selectedlist =atoi(s.c_str());
            selectedlist2 =atoi(g.c_str());
    } while ((
                 selectedlist== 0 && 
                 s != "0" && 
                 (selectedlist > 3 || selectedlist < 1)
             ) && 
             (
                  selectedlist2== 0 && 
                  g != "0" && 
                  (selectedlist2 > 3 || selectedlist2 < 1)
             )
            );
        Lista[selectedlist-1]+Lista[selectedlist2-1];
        std::cout<<"Ready";

   break;
```

In the header file:

```
class lista
{
    public:
        enum Exceptions{EMPTY};
        lista() : first(NULL),last(NULL),current(NULL){ first = new Elem(0,0);}
        virtual ~lista();
        lista(const lista& s);
        int Current() const {return current->Adat;}
        void First()   {current = first->next;}
        bool End()     const {return current==NULL;}
        void Next()    {current = current->next;}
        void Vegere(int e);
        void Elejerol();
        bool Urese();
        int Eleje();
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const lista& a);
        friend lista operator+(lista& a, lista& b);

    private:
        struct Elem{
                    int Adat;
                    Elem* next;
                    Elem(int c, Elem* n): Adat(c), next(n){};
                    };
        Elem* first;
        Elem* last;
        Elem* current;
};
```

And in the lista.cpp:

```
lista operator+(lista& a, lista& b)
{
  if(b.first->next!=NULL && a.first->next!=NULL)
    {
        a.last->next = b.first->next;
        a.last = b.last;
        b.first = new lista::Elem(0,0);
        b.last = NULL;
        b.current = NULL;
    }
   else
   {
        throw lista::EMPTY;
   }
    return a;
}

void lista::Vegere(int e) { 
  Elem* p = new Elem(e,0); 
  if(last==NULL) { 
     first -> next = p; 
     last = p; 
  } 
  else { 
    last -> next = p; 
    last = p; 
  } 
}
```

It complains, and all the other functions(empty, add numbers, etc..) works fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
void lista::Vegere(int e) 
{ 
    Elem* p = new Elem(e,0); 
    if(last==NULL) 
    { 
        first -> next = p; last = p; 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        last -> next = p; last = p; 
    } 
}
```

Destructor:

```
lista::~lista()
{
    Elem *p, *v;
    p = first;
    v = first -> next;
    while( v!=NULL)
    {
        delete p;
        p = v;
        v = v -> next;
    }
    delete p;
}
```

I have figured it out.
I havent posted this part of the code here, but after some debugging I've got it.

Here is the error:

```
    lista::lista(const lista& s){
        if(s.first->next==NULL)
        {
            first->next = last = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
        Elem* q = new Elem(s.first->Adat,NULL);
        first = q;
        for(Elem* p=s.first->next;p!=NULL;p=p->next)
        {
            q = new Elem(p->Adat,NULL);
            q->next = q;
        }
        last = q;
        }

        current = first;

THIS PART is the error:
[
        while(current!=NULL && current->Adat!=s.current->Adat)
        {
            current=current->next;
        }
]
    }
```

I've just deleted it, and it works. :)

Comment: Just a guess: try remove next from a.first->next (i.e. change to a.first!=null) and similarly for b.first, a.last, b.last

Comment: If i comment the whole define from "if(b.first->next!=NULL && a.first->next!=NULL)" to "return a;" of course I get a warning, but it does the same fault :(

Comment: Can you post the code for `Vegere(int)`? I assume this means `append`, right?

Comment: void lista::Vegere(int e)
{

    Elem* p = new Elem(e,0);
    if(last==NULL)
    {
        first -> next = p;
        last = p;
    }
    else
    {
        last -> next = p;
        last = p;
    }
}

Comment: Yes, it appends a number to the end of the list.

Comment: And the code for the destructor please. You can post it in the question body, just edit your question.

Comment: OK, this is my first post here, Im tryin to learn it :)

Comment: Ive added the destructor.

Comment: Short summary: your code is full of issues, so it is not easy to isolate the issue that leads to the segfault ;)

Comment: I don't think it's your problem, but the condition on the while is strange.  If `selectedList == 0`, then it *must* be `< 1` (so the comparison with 3 is peculiar).  What are you actually trying to do there?

Comment: Just want to get a number between 1-3.

Comment: The semantic of your `operator +` is pretty unusual. It should return a new list with concatenated items; it should not modify `a`; it should not modify `b`. Your implementation would better fit `operator +=` but even then, `b` should not be modified.

Comment: The exercise is to concat two list, into the first and then delete or make NULL the second one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
lista operator+(lista& a, lista& b)
{
    ...
    return a;
}
```

This creates a *copy* of `a` which is then immediately destroyed (because you don't save it anywhere).  You haven't defined a copy constructor, so you get the compiler defined one (which just copies the pointers).  The destructor of the temporary will delete the memory pointed to by `a.first`, and then when you come to call the destructor of `a`, everything will blow up.

If your destructor is freeing memory, you need to declare a copy constructor and and a copy assignment operator.  The simplest such definition is to just delete them (with trailing `= delete;`) - you will then need to change the definition of `operator +` (probably by changing the function name to `append()`).

Comment: I will try it, thanks for your help.